# Tutorials: launch file problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a new user of Linux and ROS. I'm running the Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.
I meet some problems with the tutorials on roslaunch.
Using the launch file turtlemimic.launch:

```
<launch>

<group ns="turtlesim1">
<node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
</group>

<group ns="turtlesim2">
<node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
</group>

<node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
<remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
<remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

After running the launch file, I can get two turtlesims started. Command

```
$ rostopic pub /turtlesim1/turtle1/command_velocity turtlesim/Velocity -r 1 --   2.0  -1.8
```

also allowed me to control the two turtles moving in circles.
But after I ran the command

```
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

the result shows as followed:

```
                 /turtlesim1/turtle1/pose         /turtlesim2/turtle1/command_velocity
/turtlesim1/sim --------------------------> /mimic--------------------> /turtlesim2/sim
```

This is different from the one in tutorials:

```
              /turtle1/command_velocity
 teleop_turtle-----------------------> 
              /turtle1/command_velocity  /turtlesim
 rostopic....------------------------>
```

I don't know whether it's the problem of my setting or not. The result I got makes more sense to me.
I also tried to add several lines in the launch file:

```
  <node pkg="turtlesim" name="tele" type="turtle_teleop_key">
  <remap from="output" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
  </node>
```

But I still can't control the turtle using keyboard. I checked the node information of "tele", the results are:

```
Node [/tele]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
* /turtle1/command_velocity [turtlesim/Velocity]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
* /tele/get_loggers
* /tele/set_logger_level


contacting node htt p://localhost:36452/ ...
Pid: 9285
Connections:
* topic: /rosout
* to: /rosout
* direction: outbound
* transport: TCPROS
```

Can anyone tell me what's happening? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51625/tutorials:-launch-file-problem/) by [aldaris](https://answers.ros.org/users/3903/aldaris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aldaris](https://answers.ros.org/users/3903/aldaris/) on 2013-01-08**:
It seems that I can't comment under your answer. Thank you very much for you help. It works. It also helps me to better understand how nodes communicate with each other. I have never edit ROS wiki before, I will try later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

This is a nice extension to a good tutorial. If you can understand how to fix this, you're well on your way...
Can I suggest next time writing a more detailed subject? e.g. "connecting turtlesim teleop to turtlesim mimic"

Here's how to debug it:

When you run the teleop node, do:

> $ rostopic list

and you'll see that it outputs to the topic:

> /turtle1/command_velocity

But earlier in the tutorial, you sent a command to the turtle manually on the topic:

> /turtlesim1/turtle1/command_velocity

using the command:

> rostopic pub
> /turtlesim1/turtle1/command_velocity
> turtlesim/Velocity -r 1 -- 2.0  -1.8

So therefore you need to launch the teleop node, and re-map the output from the teleop node to the command topic of the first turtle

Here's a launch file with the existing code to start two turtles, plus it launches the teleop node and remaps the teleop topic:

```
<launch>

<group ns="turtlesim1">
<node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
</group>

<group ns="turtlesim2">
<node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
</group>

<node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
<remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
<remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
</node>

<node pkg="turtlesim" name="teleop" type="turtle_teleop_key">
  <remap from="/turtle1/command_velocity" to="/turtlesim1/turtle1/command_velocity"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

Would you like to add this to the end of the tutorial on the Wiki?

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2